# (jQuery Highchart) How to make this as Horizontal Bars?

Tags: jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

What i need is exactly with this following chart.
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

But unfortunately it is vertical one as i'm need the **horizontal one**. But when i change the `type: bar`, it is then appearing with **separated bars** while the original one is combined one. How can i have it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following coded on jsfiddle. there is a slight change in the code

http://jsfiddle.net/ayJYV/2/

Comment: Great work, @Rab Nawaz Khan. But the original one have the `Summary Total Number` for each bars. Is it possible for the horizontal one?

Comment: i mean `Total Count` at the end of bar, as original one :(