# How to add negative area or background for a specific bar or pie chart in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Using highcharts, how would I put a default grey bar under my column charts, for example, like [this](http://daytum.com/)?

And how would I do something similar for a pie chart (if my data takes up 30% of the chart, show the remaining 70% as light grey or something similar to denote unused space of the pie chart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Pie chart there has been a bit of a back and forth in the highcharts forums. What I would do is get all of your data you need to plot and find out what percentage of the total all of that data is. Then, with the remaining percentage create another data point and set its color to grey.
But you really have to consider what is the total percentage means - without further detail I cannot begin to guess.

As for the first question about "default grey bar under my column charts" it is not clear from that link what you mean. I do not really see what you mean with the charts I have looked at.

Comment: Thanks.  That's not a bad suggestion at all.  Also, somewhat unrelated, but do you know of any quick way to set the color for all the data points in a pie chart without setting each data points's color individually?  And in terms of the bar chart, the idea is the same -- we have a total length that could be grey, and the colored section is the percentage of the total that I track for.  Not sure if there is an easier way w/highcharts.

Comment: For the bar do you  mean something like a gantt chart (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart)? There are some hacks to get it to work (http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10096). As for setting the colors ahead of time (not setting them individually in the data object) - yes, you can do that. You can pass in a string of colors for HighCharts to use and if you order them correctly it should work (http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#colors). Note that this is global so any charts on your page will use these colors. If you have 5 series and 4 colors it loops back to first color in list.

Comment: Not a gantt chart, and this may not be the best example but [here](http://feltron.com/ar10_05.html) if you look at the 'postcards from' section there is a max length for each bar, but each bar still is only as big as its proportion to the other values.  Maybe use highcharts 'stacked' option, calculate the rest of the way to the end of the div and give it a grey color?

Comment: Ah, I get what you want now. Check out this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595141/jquery-highchart-how-to-make-this-as-horizontal-bars) and this linked jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ayJYV/2/). For you just have a value max of say 100 and your current data as a fraction of that then a second series of the remainder.